React - useState updated from childComponent without using setter
I've encountered quite a weird behaviour in ReactJS and it looks like I'm able to update a useState without using a useState setter. First thing first, my useState is declared in the root component and it holds all the data my tool needs.
const RootComponent = () => {

    ...

    const [data, setData] = useState(extractData(rawData))

    return(
         ...
         //child components are declared here, here's an example
         <ChildComponent
             data={data}
             setData={setData}
         >
    );
}

The child components often take input from the user and for that reason I pass down setData to them so they can update the useState. The structure of my tool is pretty complex and I often render react components using the map function. To avoid having to access all the nested properties of the useState object in every component, I pass down the specific data needed by that component just like this:
const LeafComponents = ({data, setData}) => {
    
    return(
        <Fragment>
            {specificData.map((specificData) => (
                <Fragment key={specificData.id}>
                    <LeafComponent
                        specificData={specificData} />
                </Fragment>
            ))}
        </Fragment>
    );
}

This is where the weird thing happens. In LeafComponent I have a textbox linked to a useState textContent. Everytime the user types in the textbox, the useState is updated AND everytime textContent changes, specificData's text property is given a new value.
const LeafComponent = ({specificData}) => {

    const [textContent, setTextContent] = useState("")

    const handleTextContent = (event) => {
        setTextContent(event.target.value)
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
        specificData.text = textContent
    }, [textContent, specificData])

    return(
         <textarea
              value={textContent}
              onChange={handleTextContent}>
         </textarea>
    );
}

specificData is "part of" a useState and the assignment you see above shouldn't update it because setData wasn't used. To check if that was the case I debugged this way.
const RootComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(extractData(rawData))
    
    useEffect(()=> {
        console.log(data)
    }, [data])

    function handleButtonPress() {
        console.log(data)
    }

    return(
        ...

        <button onClick={handleButtonPress}/>

        ...
    ) 

The console.log in the useEffect is never activated but the console.log in the handleButtonPress returns the value of data containing the updated value of specifcData.textbox. How is that possible if a setter wasn't used? Why is the useEffect never activated?

This is because you're unintentionally mutating state.
When your state is an object or an array, the actual state value is a reference to that object (array). Direct mutation to that object is against the rules of React, and while it sometimes appears to work correctly it can very quickly cause hard to find bugs.
In this case, you appear to be mutating a nested value of your state, which can be even harder to detect. specificData.text = textContent is mutating the original state's nested object.
This may appear to update the state in cases where the component re-renders for other reasons, but it will not trigger a re-render itself - causing odd behaviors including skipped renders.
To correct this, you would need to create a copy of the data before mutating it using spread syntax or similar newData = {...specificData, text: textContent}.
